# Speed up Python startup or connect it with VB.NET

Tags: python, vb.net

I've got a following setup:
VB.NET Web-Service is running and it needs to regularly call Python script with machine learning model to predict some stuff. To do this my Web-Service generates a file with input for Python and runs Python script as a subprocess. The script makes predictions and returns them, as standard output, back to Web-Service.

The problem is, that the script requires a few seconds to import all the machine learning libraries and load saved model from drive. It's much more than doing actual prediction. During this time Web-Service is blocked by running subprocess. I have to reduce this time drastically.

What I need is a solution to either:
1. Improve libraries and model loading time.
2. Communicate Python script with VB.NET Web-Service and run Python all the time with imports and ML model already loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found what I needed.

I've used web.py to convert the Python script into a Web-Service and now both VB.NET and Python Web-Services can communicate. Python is running all the time, so there is no delay for loading libraries and data each time a calculation have to be done.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understood the question but here are some things I can think of.
If this is a network thing you should have python compress the code before sending it over the web.

Or if you're able to, use multithreading while reading the file from the web.

Maybe you should upload some more code so we can help you better.